# Analytical flux on circular geometry

Tags: flux, surface

I have a problem where I need to compare analytical and numerical flux around a circular geometry defined by x^2+y^2=0.5^2.

The flux is defined by grad(u).n where I choose u_analytical to be (x^2+y^2 , 0) in 2 dimensions.
The n in the formula is the surface normal of the circle so I think it is
(2x/sqrt(4x^2+4y^2) , 2y/sqrt(4x^2+4y^2) ). So my flux in x direction only is 
(4x^2/sqrt(4x^2+4y^2) + 4y^2/sqrt(4x^2+4y^2)) but my numerical solution is far from that. Do I do any fundamental mistake here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I now figured this out after reading some other related/similar posts. The easiest way to think is converting surface integral of the flux \int_S (grad(u).n) dS to volume integral \int_V div (grad(u)) dV using divergence theorem. From there I know div (grad(u)) = 4 and dV is the area of the circle = pi*r^2 that makes 4*pi*r^2 is the analytical flux.